# Hibernate schema validation error for timestamp column

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-time

While converting from joda.time classes to java.time classes in application using Spring Boot 2.7.0, Hibernate 5.2.10.Final, Java 11, I have run into a problem with an error being thrown from Hibernate schema validation phase.

The error is

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column
> [header_date_created] in table [daily_ count]; found [date
> (Types#DATE)], but expecting [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)]
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:167)
> at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:151)

The postgresql column definition is timestamp.

The column in the @Entity Java class is defined as:

```
@Column(name = " header_date_created")
private Date headerDateCreated;
```

I have even tried to use the java.persistence annotations of `@Basic` and `@Temporal` to clarify the type. But the same error is triggered.  Tried both `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` and `TemporalType.DATE` but it made no difference.

In the database schema all dates are defined as SQL type timestamp.  When using joda.time classes the entity used LocalDateTime.   Now with the conversion I am using java.util.Date.  This worked type works for entities using JPA Auditing with the @CreatedDate and @LastModifedDate annotations but using it for other date members cause the above error.

Other types I have tried are the OffsetDateTime and the LocalDateTime classes but the result is always the same.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.   Anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: *While converting from joda.time classes to java.time classes ...* Neither `Date` class (`java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`) has got anything to do with java.time. You intended to take a step forward but instead are taking a step backward. I suggest that the easy solution is simply replacing the Joda-Time `LocalDateTme` with `java.time.LocalDateTime`. Uder all circumstances forget about `Date`.

Comment: Tried the LocalDateTime class as well, but results in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be a discrepancy in DDL.  The column definition ended up being date, not timestamp.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).